# How to show the panel in postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two radio button in group called `purchase and Expenses`.
When i click purchase radio button, that will show `panelpurchase`,similarly `panelexpense` will show for Expenses radio button.

watch image of output[when pageload panelpurchase visible false using jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDad1.png)

when i click purchase radio button that will show **panelpurchase**[panelpurchase show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y2IQ.png).

now what i want is when i click the add button in panelpurchase that page will reload (postpack) and that postback page should display that panel purchase.

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#PanelPurchase').hide();
        $('#PanelExpensive').hide();
        $('#<%= RadioPurchase.ClientID %>').click(function () { $('#PanelPurchase').show(); $('#PanelExpensive').hide(); });
        $('#<%= RadioExpensive.ClientID %>').click(function () { $('#PanelPurchase').hide(); $('#PanelExpensive').show(); });

        $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
            alert("faisal");
            //$('#PanelPurchase').show(); $('#PanelExpensive').hide();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Back end c# code:

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelPurchase.Visible = true;
        Response.Write("server working");
    }
```

Comment: Can we do postback in jquery?.

Comment: is that neccessary that you need a post back??
you could do the same thing with the JQuery.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny How?.. Can you tell me. when i click that add button that entire panel went hide

Comment: $('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});

here is the function to reload using javascript.

Comment: if there is any change in the page that happens after you reload the page, then, you would use that changed value as the parameter and use JQuery to show the div.

like, if you would update some flag which says the page is reloaded and then use that flag to manipulate the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button click you call the javascript function like below;

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelPurchase.Visible = true;
        Response.Write("server working");
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
    }
```

Then define the javascript function,

```
function MyFunction()
{
   $('#PanelPurchase').show();
   $('#PanelExpensive').hide();

}
```

Comment: @MohamedFaisalAbbas,  which issue you are facing now? you got page reload?

Comment: I got page reload, but the PanelPurchase went hide, because of ` $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#PanelPurchase').hide();`

Comment: @Ponmanu Chinnaswamy I got the solution in a different way. by adding one hidden text i did it. thanks bro